# Laravel 5 global date accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I watched a few Laracast lessons and now I'm building my first Laravel project. I have a few Eloquent models with timestamps for created_at and updated_at.

For displaying the right date format Laravel has a very nice functionality: accessors. But in EVERY Eloquent model I now have 2 functions like this:

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
```

This way the date will be forced to show as `d-m-Y H:i:s`. The only problem is: I don't want to do this for every Model I create..

Is there a default Laravel way/convention I can do this globally or should I just make some kind of `MasterModel` and extend that instead of `Model`?

Comment: Have a look at--    http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers

Comment: make a main class and inherit your models from main

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to provide accessor to change the date format. It's enough to set the $**dateFormat** variable in your model, e.g.:

```
class User extends Model {
  protected $dateFormat = 'U'; // this will give you a timestamp
}
```

You can read more about available formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Secondly, if you don't want to set the **$dateFormat** variable for all your models, set it there and make all your models extend that class:

```
class BaseModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}

class User extends BaseModel {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's the beauty of OOP

Comment: Why is this beautiful OOP? Inheritance for sharing properties only is a bad practice.

Comment: Creating a parent class just for this is bad. Use a trait instead.

Comment: You are sure $dateFormat is an accessor ? Can't find it in the doc

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for the same, but unfortunately couldn't come up with a way to create a global accessor.

The "problem" with the dateFormat property, is that it is a mutator, not an accessor. And extending a base class doesn't work for both the User model and other models because it extends Authenticatable, and not the Model directly.

Here's what I did as the next best thing - I created a `FormatsDates` trait. With your methods:

```
trait FormatsDates
{
    protected $newDateFormat = 'd-m-Y H:i:s';

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value) {
       return Carbon::parse($value)->format($this->newDateFormat);
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format($this->newDateFormat);
    }
}
```

Now I can use this trait on any model I want. e.g. the User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use FormatsDates;
}
```

Maybe somebody finds this useful.

Comment: Where exactly did you put this trait code...in which file?

Comment: Wherever you want. In my case it's in `app\Models\Support\FormatsDates.php`.

Comment: I was working through extending the base Model class and you saved me few hours by pointing that the User model doesn't extend the base class. Thanks!